# Distance between vector and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I'm currently practicing for my Linear Algebra exam and I am trying to solve the following question:

> [image]

I solved a and I'm pretty sure that's correct:

The orthonormal basis for V is:

- x1 = (1/3)[1 2 -2 0]
- x2 = 1/(sqrt(3)[0 1 1 1]
- x3 = 1/sqrt(6)[2 -1 0 1]

But I'm not sure if I have the correct answer for b. I first projected y on V which results in: [5 3 -8 -1]. Then i did ||y - projected_y|| which results in sqrt(18). Which would mean the distance between y and V is sqrt(18).

Could anyone tell me if this is correct? :)

Comment: In the future, please take the time to type in important parts of your question instead of pasting an image. Images of text are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of projecting $y$ on $V$ and then analyzing the norm of $\lVert y - Proj_y \rVert$ is correct. Also, notice that another way that you could solve this problem is to project $y$ about any vector perpendicular to $V$ and take the norm of this projection itself! :)

Comment: The nice thing about the second approach suggest here is that a perpendicular vector can be found without orthogonalizing the basis of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V=[v_1,v_2,v_3]$, then the subspace is exactly the set $\{Vx\mid x\in\Bbb R^3\}$. Now, consider the function 
$$f(x)=\|y-Vx\|_2^2.$$
Can you: 1) show that $f$ is differentiable and convex; 2) work out a local minimum (which by convexité is also the global minimum)?